# Win->Alt key remapping in AutoHotKey can not work well

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey, remap

I wrote a [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com) script to remap *LWin* to *LAlt*

```
LWin::LAlt
LWin & Tab::AltTab
```

*LWin+Tab* works OK. But I found, for example in my emacs, *LWin+b* can not work as *Alt+b*. And if I disable this statment

```
LWin & Tab::AltTab
```

*LWin+b* works. But I know *LWin+Tab* will not works very good without this remapping statement as mentioned in [AutoHotKey Remapping](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure why, but it seems the first key mapped can only be declared once. I have found a solution (although not perfect) of writing the second command as so: Tab & LWin::AltTab. This means that you have to hold Tab down first though.